# Where and when does Dream find the saeculum?

Tags: the-sandman

At the end of *Overture*, it's revealed that Desire stole Time's saeculum (sæculum) from Dream, and hid it for Dream to find at a particular time later.

Was this discovery depicted or mentioned in a previous volume?

Comment: I edited out the SPOILER part, because it doesn't look nice and what you're asking about isn't really an essential part of the plot (not really a spoiler).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I was on mobile and unsure of the protocol. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers

Comment: +1 for finding that meta question alone :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Saeculum was found by the next aspect of Dream, who was previously known as Daniel Hall.

This happens some time after the events of the last volume of *The Sandman*. In *Overture*, the time period is simply referred to as "now":

[image]

The Saeculum ended up with Mad Hettie, for some reason. Dream finds it in *Overture* #2, and immediately sends it back to Father (Time).

[image]

In *Overture* #4 we see that Father has received it. (And here we have the first example of a bootstrap paradox in *The Sandman* universe)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had thought that the pocket watch found earlier in *Overture* was the one given to him by Prez Rickard in *World's End*. But I see now the clues in wording ("now", "cannot argue with time", "not actually *you*") and illustration (the cards). Hm.